# Passing Variables into a SQL String

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

Can someone help me with the syntax attached

```
DECLARE @SearchString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET     @SearchString = 'fletc'

USE [Prodution]
GO

SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE Username LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
```

I am trying to concatenate the LIKE statement at the bottom.  However, I am getting the error message attached:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@SearchString".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Rob

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of `GO` terminates a scope (so all variables declared before it are "lost") - move your declaration to **after** the `GO`:

```
USE [Production]
GO

DECLARE @SearchString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET     @SearchString = 'fletc'

SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE Username LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
```

Comment: Hello Marc, many thanks for your help.  It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
DECLARE @SearchString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET     @SearchString = 'fletc'

USE [Prodution]
GO

SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE Username LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
```

there's a GO statement. Visibility starts again after GO